# Clean all spaces and newlines C or Lex/Bison

Tags: c, bison, lex

I need to clean all spaces and newlines (\n) of the yytext on my Lex/Bison program.

I have a proprierty like this:

```
<PROPERTY>[^}]* TAG=yytext;
```

I need it to parse all my CSS code file into the HTML tags.

I tried something like this:

```
sizeOfArray=strlen(TAG);
int i;
for(i=0; i<sizeOfArray; i++){
    memmove(TAG,TAG+1,len);
}
```

Without success...

EDIT:

I only want clean the spaces before the property and after it.

example:

```
 body {
         background: black;
         color: #80c0c0
         }
```

Because I want put this lines on my HTML file, to be something like this:

```
<body style="background:black; color:#80c0c0;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but if `isspace()` from `<ctype.h>` matches the characters (blanks, tabs, newlines) that you want to skip, this should work:

```
int sizeOfArray = strlen(TAG);
int i, j;
for (i = j = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
{
    if (!isspace(TAG[i]))
        TAG[j++] = TAG[i];
}
TAG[j] = '\0';
```

---

As discussed in the comments, this code should implement 'for each sequence of one or more newlines or spaces, preserve a single space; copy other characters through unchanged', again assuming `isspace()` is a suitable function — there's also `isblank()`, for example, in the Standard C library.

```
int sizeOfArray = strlen(TAG);
int i, j;
for (i = j = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
{
    if (isspace(TAG[i]))
    {
        while (i < sizeOfArray && isspace(TAG[i]))
            i++;
        if (TAG[i] != '\0')
            TAG[j++] = ' ';
    }
    TAG[j++] = TAG[i];
}
TAG[j] = '\0';
```

Now tested with this SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)):

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void squish_whitespace(char *TAG)
{
    int sizeOfArray = strlen(TAG);
    int i, j;
    for (i = j = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        if (isspace(TAG[i]))
        {
            while (i < sizeOfArray && isspace(TAG[i]))
                i++;
            if (TAG[i] != '\0')
                TAG[j++] = ' ';
        }
        TAG[j++] = TAG[i];
    }
    TAG[j] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char data[][80] =
    {
        "abc def ghi",
        "abc  def   \t\t\n\nghi",
        "abc  def  ghi   ",
        "body {\n"                        // NB: string concatenation
        "        background: black;\n"
        "        color: #80c0c0\n"
        "     }"
    };
    enum { NUM_DATA = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]) };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_DATA; i++)
    {
        printf("Before: [[%s]]\n", data[i]);
        squish_whitespace(data[i]);
        printf("After:  [[%s]]\n", data[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output from test data:

```
Before: [[abc def ghi]]
After:  [[abc def ghi]]
Before: [[abc  def          

ghi]]
After:  [[abc def ghi]]
Before: [[abc  def  ghi   ]]
After:  [[abc def ghi]]
Before: [[body {
        background: black;
        color: #80c0c0
     }]]
After:  [[body { background: black; color: #80c0c0 }]]
```

Comment: OH god... you saved my day, last 6 hours trying to figured out this.

Comment: So... I missed one thing on the question, I only need the \n and the spaces only before or after each property.

Comment: With your code I got this: `border:thickdashedblue;` and it shoulded be: `border: thick dashed blue;`

Comment: So, you need a more precise specification of what you want than 'clean all newlines and spaces'.  Maybe what you mean is 'for each sequence of one or more newlines or spaces, preserve a single space; copy other characters through unchanged'.  That is a fairly straight-forward adaptation of the code shown.  But if that's not what you want either, you need to specify the requirement carefully.

Comment: Yes it's exactly that, I edited my question, it's not clear yet? Thank you @Jonathan.

Comment: Perfect. Do you know if that space on the begin of each property makes some difference?

Comment: I don't know.  If it does matter, you can tweak the code to skip leading blanks (`if (TAG[i] != '\0' && j > 0) TAG[j++] = ' ';` would probably do the trick).  That sort of thing should be fairly straight-forward to handle (or, perhaps, in thirty years time, it will be second nature to you if you keep practicing).

Comment: Perfect, It's really awesome how you can solve this in few minutes, many years coding C, I think. Thank you for your time! Anyway I think you was ironic with that 30 years joke lol.